# Python script chokes on a downloaded file because of unicode encode error

Tags: python, unicode, python-requests, encode

I run a script 4 times a day that uses the requests module to download a file, which I then throw into a database.  9 times out of 10, the script works flawlessly.  But the times it does not work is because of a character in the downloaded file that my script, as it is, does not like.  For example, here's the error I got today: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 379-381: ordinal not in range(128)`.  I downloaded the file another way and here's the character at position 380 which I believe is responsible for stopping my script, "∞".  And, here's the place in my script where it chokes:

```
##### request file

r = requests.get('https://resources.example.com/requested_file.csv')

##### create the database importable csv file

ld = open('/requested_file.csv', 'w')
print(r.text, file=ld)
```

I know this probably has to do with encoding the file somehow before printing it to the .csv file, and is probably a simple thing for someone who knows what they are doing but, after many hours of research, I'm about to cry.  Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856610/python-3-unicode-encode-error

Comment: You'll need to know the encoding ([see here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)). Does whoever posts the csv files tell you what to use?

Comment: @tdelaney this looks like python3 from the print function - so [these docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). Not sure if anything changed.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `ld.write(r.text)`?

Comment: No, they do not tell which encoding to use, @tdelaney.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of different things but here's what ended up working for me:

```
import requests
import io

##### request file

r = requests.get('https://resources.example.com/requested_file.csv')

##### create the db importable csv file

with open('requested_file_TEMP.csv', 'wb') as ld:
ld.write(r.text.encode())
ld.close()

##### run the temp file through the following code to get rid of any non-ascii characters
##### in the file; non-ascii characters can/will cause the script to choke

with io.open('requested_file_TEMP.csv', 'r',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as infile, \
io.open('requested_file_TEMP.csv', 'w',encoding='ascii',errors='ignore') as outfile:
for line in infile:
    print(*line.split(), file=outfile)
infile.close
outfile.close
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an *encoding* for your file; currently it defaults to ASCII, which is a very limited codec.

You could use UTF-8 instead, for example:

```
with open('/requested_file.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as ld:
    print(r.text, file=ld)
```

However, since you are loading from a URL you are now decoding then encoding again. A better idea is to just copy the data straight to disk as bytes. Make a *streaming* request and have `shutil.copyfileobj()` copy the data in chunks. That way you can handle any size of response without loading everything into memory:

```
import requests
import shutil

r = requests.get('https://resources.example.com/requested_file.csv', stream=True)
with open('/requested_file.csv', 'wb') as ld:
    r.raw.decode_content = True  # decompress gzip or deflate responses
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, ld)
```

Comment: Did this but now get a different but similar error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 379: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: @JeffF: sounds like you have a new question; something is trying to decode bytes as ASCII. For your posted code that could mean the server told `requests` that the text data was encoded using `ASCII` but in reality it is not. `C3` is not a valid ASCII codepoint.

Comment: @JeffF: since you are copying URL data straight to a file, better to open the file in binary mode and just copy the data across straight. No decoding, no encoding.