# Unicode Encode Error (python)

Tags: python

i am getting the following pythonerror -

```
Unicode Encode Error charmap codec cannot encode character '\u2026' in position 143 character maps to <undefined>
```

### Follwing is the code

```
from twython import Twython
consumer_key
consumer_secret
access_key
access_sceret
t=Twython(app_key=consumer_key,app_secret=consumer_secret,oauth_token=access_key,oauth_token_secret=access_sceret)

search = t.search(q='#tiago',count=100)

tweets = search['statuses']

for tweet in tweets:
  print (tweet['id_str'], '\n', tweet['text'], '\n\n\n')
```

** i have used command - `python setup.py install` to unzip Twython module in directory which is different from the directory where my code is

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Are you using Windows? Have you set up your terminal to handle Unicode? FWIW, codepoint 2026 is `…`

Comment: python 3.4 , windows , have set the path for enviroment variables

Comment: attribute error : 'non type' has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @Sagar Do have a look at [Python 3 unicode encode error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17856610)