# How to resolve "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' " in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, data-extraction

I am relatively new to Python. I have this code that extracts data from Twitter using Hashtags and saves them in a CSV file. It runs well in Python 2.7 but when I tried running it in Python 3 it gives me, `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` as follows:
[image]

```
import json
import csv
import tweepy
import re
"""
INPUTS:
    consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret: codes 
    telling twitter that we are authorized to access this data
    hashtag_phrase: the combination of hashtags to search for
OUTPUTS:
    none, simply save the tweet info to a spreadsheet
"""
def search_for_hashtags(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret, hashtag_phrase):
    
    #create authentication for accessing Twitter
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    #initialize Tweepy API
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    #get the name of the spreadsheet we will write to
    fname = '_'.join(re.findall(r"#(\w+)", hashtag_phrase))

    #open the spreadsheet we will write to
    with open('%s.csv' % (fname), 'wb') as file:

        w = csv.writer(file)

        #write header row to spreadsheet
        w.writerow(['timestamp', 'tweet_text', 'username', 'all_hashtags', 'followers_count'])

        #for each tweet matching our hashtags, write relevant info to the spreadsheet
        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=hashtag_phrase+' -filter:retweets', \
                                   lang="en", tweet_mode='extended').items(100):
            w.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.replace('\n',' ').encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.screen_name.encode('utf-8'), [e['text'] for e in tweet._json['entities']['hashtags']], tweet.user.followers_count])
consumer_key = input('Consumer Key ')
consumer_secret = input('Consumer Secret ')
access_token = input('Access Token ')
access_token_secret = input('Access Token Secret ')
    
hashtag_phrase = input('Hashtag Phrase ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_for_hashtags(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret, hashtag_phrase)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think it does. But unfortunately, I an into another error now: https://ibb.co/qpBJkNs (Click on the link to see the error). Please see if you are able to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17856610/13552470).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
with open('%s.csv' % (fname), 'wb') as file:
```

into

```
with open('%s.csv' % (fname), 'w') as file:
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But now, I am getting the following error: https://ibb.co/qpBJkNs (Click on the link to see the error)